# what is ExternalAccessory Protocol used IOS

Tags: ios, ipa

Please, how can I specify the protocol used by my external accessory in my code?
In my info.plist file, I put the key but I do not know what I have to put in items. thanks

Answer (score 2):

Examine the `protocolStrings` property of the `EAAccessory` object when you receive a `EAAccessoryDidConnect` notification. Those are the protocols you should put in your info.plist file, under the key `UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols`

For example,

```
<key>UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols</key>
<array>
    <string>PROTOCOL_NAME_HERE</string>
    <string>PROTOCOL_NAME_HERE</string>
</array>
```

If you're unsure about how to implement the `EAAccessoryDelegate` protocol to obtain what I describe above, have a look at `EADemo` sample from Apple

Comment: This would be a better answer if instead of `PROTOCOL_NAME_HERE` it included some actual, real-world values that might be used there.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the time, you get the protocol name from hardware manufactory.

For example, if you develop iOS apps work with Pebble watch, the value will be
"com.getpebble.public"