# How to discover already connected devices using the ExternalAccessoryFramework on iOS for a non-MFI Bluetooth device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, ios-bluetooth, external-accessory

I am writing an app that seeks to discover if the user is already connected to a specialized Bluetooth keyboard that I produce. My peripheral is running Bluetooth Classic, version 3.0, and uses HID to communicate with the iOS device. I cannot use Apple's CoreBluetooth Framework as I am not using BluetoothLE or GATT. I must use Apple's ExternalAccessory framework. As per Apple's rules, I DO NOT need to register with MFI because I use "standard Bluetooth profiles supported by iOS" (see [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204387)).

I tried to find the connected Bluetooth peripheral by the following objective-c snippet:

`NSArray<EAAccessory *> *accessories = [[EAAccessoryManager sharedAccessoryManager] connectedAccessories];`

However, even when my Bluetooth peripheral is connected to the iOS device, I cannot obtain any connectedAccessories when I run this command. Do I need to include a `UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols` field in my info.plist file despite not using MFI? See [this related stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17236701/what-is-externalaccessory-protocol-used-ios) for the `UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols` field.
Do I need to programatically connect with my peripheral in objective-c before it returns as a connected device (even though the iOS device is already connected to the peripheral via Bluetooth)? I am really stuck, and don't know how to proceed. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You don't need to register with MFi because you are using a standard keyboard HID profile, but if your device doesn't include an MFi chipset and identifier you will not discover it via external accessory framework.

Comment: Thanks Paul. How might I go about accessing my Bluetooth peripheral through software? There must be some way to access it programatically, no?

Comment: You might be able to use IOSs dual mode Bluetooth support - https://developer.apple.com/wwdc19/901 ?

Comment: Thanks, but I believe that the updates to CoreBluetooth in 2019 only made GATT Bluetooth Classic devices compatible. I'm using HID, so I don't think this would work.

Comment: Yes, I don't believe that there is any way for your app to interact with your peripheral unless it also supports the GATT profile.

Comment: That's annoying. Thanks for your help.